# Python (sklearn) train_test_split: choosing which data to train and which data to test

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to use sklearn's train_test_split to manually split data into train and test categories. Specifically, in my .csv file, I want to use all the rows of data until the last row to train, and the last row to test.

The reason I'm doing this is because I need to launch a machine learning model but am incredibly short on time. I thought the best way would be to use predictions rather than deploying it using IBM Watson. I don't need it to be live.  My code so far looks like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv('Book5.csv', names=['Amiability', 'Email'])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df_x = df['Amiability']
df_y = df['Email']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
```

Then,

```
len(df)
```

Produces

```
331
```

I want to train with rows 0-330, and test with row 331. How can I do this?

Comment: You can use pythonic way to access this. 
`x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=df_x[:-1],df_x[-1:],df_y[:-1], df_y[-1:]`

Comment: What does this do, and how can I adjust it to my needs?

Comment: This is one of the ways python does slicing. 
You can just use this or the one @jch has shared.

Comment: And just for clarity you are printing `df's` len and not the `x_train` and/or others.

Comment: Yes. But how do I cut off the data such that the first 330 rows go to training and the last 1 row goes to testing?

Comment: The slicing code that @teedak8s has supplied does exactly that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't absolutely need the test row to be the last row you should be able to do:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df_x, df_y, test_size=1, random_state=4)
```

When `test_size=` is an integer it specifies the absolute number of sample rows for the test set.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be the last row. Maybe I could make a loop until my test data is the last row, after which I could operate the code?

Comment: That loop would be way too inefficient.  Since it has to be the last row go with @teedak8s slicing solution.